# 21k rep but "Not enough reputation to answer or unprotect"

Tags: bug, protected-questions

I got a notice that an [answer I gave a while ago](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47323/can-i-use-an-lgpl-licenced-library-in-my-commercial-app/47330#47330) got upvoted. Looks like there's been some activity on the question. I saw a notice saying that I don't have enough rep to vote or unprotect the question. It seems od to me.

Comment: Are you logged in at all (i.e. do you see your avatar and reputation in the top bar) when on the main site? Could you post a screenshot perhaps? That question isn't protected, so the message is rather weird.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't seeing a (relatively new) notice for highly active questions that says that you have enough reputation to answer or unprotect this question? I'd recommend a screenshot.

Comment: @ThomasOwens That's precisely it...my mind read "you do not have" when it says "you have" I guess it just didn't occur to me that I'd be getting an alert saying I **can** do something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a PEBKAC interface error. My mind read "you do not have" when it says "you have" I guess it just didn't occur to me that I'd be getting an alert saying I can do something :)